# CRUD on XML using Java

Tags: java, xml, dom, jaxb

I am developing a java application and i am using XML to store the settings and other data in the application.I have read about Java preferences manager API but i felt storing in XML is more convenient in my application.I started usng JAXB first but then i dint find any tutorials to modify the XML once it is created.My application involves storing the Email account details of the users.As the user adds his accounts dynamically , i need to add them to XML as well.So i dint find JAXB convenient(or rather i dint find any tutorials to update or modify the XML ).The only other option i found was DOM parser here http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html .But i feel it is too complicated for such a simple application.speed , memory etc doesnt matter to me.Are there any other alternatives to do this?

Comment: How about trying it out... Then putting up the code wherever you get stuck...

Comment: There are embedded databases(with very small fotprint). Example : http://hsqldb.org/

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) can be a good (java-oriented) solution. Besides being [*Berkeley DB enables the development of custom data management solutions, without the overhead traditionally associated with such custom projects.*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/database-technologies/berkeleydb/overview/index.html) yet based on XML files. It's has a very [complete documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17277_02/html/index.html) for integration with Java lang.

Comment: This does answer the question. Please provide more relevant content here so that answer is useful as it is. Link only answers gets deleted regularly.

Answer (score 0):

With JAXB you can:

1. Unmarshal the XML into Java objects.
2. Manipulate the Java objects to modify the XML.
3. Marshal the objects producing a new XML document which you can use to replace the original XML.

Or:

1. Parse the XML into a DOM
2. Unmarshal the XML using a JAXB `Binder`
3. Modify the object
4. Use the `Binder` to apply the changes back to the DOM.
5. Write out the DOM replacing the original XML

Answer (score -1):

I like to point you to [XMLBeam](http://xmlbeam.org) (**Disclosure: I'm affiliated with that project**). This library is ideal to store configuration values in XML and while the application grows maintain the XML format without changing your Java API.

This is how IO operations look like:

```
Projection projection = projector.io().file(file).read(Projection.class);

projector.io().file(file).write(projection);
```

You get one liner IO handling and static typed access to the XML content. A pattern for configuration data would be to include a default value template in your JAR, read this if no config file was found on disk and write it back to disk on config changes. But of course you can also create documents from scratch (described in tutorials).